# Merging 2 arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have 2 arrays and I would like to combine the two arrays which will result in the third array, like in the second image. How can I do that?

```js
const mapper = {
  characters: {
    'onepiece': {
      'luffy': 'pirate king',
      'sanji': 'cook'
    },
    'deathnote': {
      'ryuk': 'shinigami',
      'lee': 'weirdo :)'
    }
  },
  animes: {
    'onepiece': 'one piece',
    'deathnote': 'death note'
  }
}
```

I wanted to have a result like this:

'Luffy : Pirate King in One Piece', 
'Sanji : Cook in One Piece', 
'Ryuk : Shinigami in Death Note', 
'Lee : Weirdo :) in Death Note'

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code.. It took you longer to make and upload a screenshot than it would have taken to just copy the code into the question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/1444609

Comment: You do not even have arrays.

Comment: Hi @epascarello sorry I uploaded the wrong screenshot. Thanks! :) I will update this question.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript implementation

```js
const mapper = {
  characters: {
    'onepiece': {
      'luffy': 'pirate king',
      'sanji': 'cook',
    },
    'deathnote': {
      'ryuk': 'shinigami',
      'lee': 'weirdo :)',
    },
  },
  animes: {
    'onepiece': 'one piece',
    'deathnote': 'death note',
  },
};

const result = Object.assign({}, mapper.characters.onepiece, mapper.characters.deathnote);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do nested a *classic* `for` / `in` loop for this.

```js
const mapper = {
  characters: {
    'onepiece': {
      'luffy': 'pirate king',
      'sanji': 'cook'
    },
    'deathnote': {
      'ryuk': 'shinigami',
      'lee': 'weirdo :)'
    }
  },
  animes: {
    'onepiece': 'one piece',
    'deathnote': 'death note'
  }
};


let result = [];
for (var key in mapper.characters) {
  for (var key2 in mapper.characters[key]) {
    result.push(jsUcfirst(key2) + " : " + jsUcfirst(mapper.characters[key][key2]) + " in " + jsUcfirst(mapper.animes[key]));
  }
}

//Capitalize first letter of each word on a string
function jsUcfirst(string) {
  let arr = [];
  string = string.split(" ");
  for (var key in string) arr.push(string[key].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string[key].slice(1));
  return arr.join(" ");
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help @TezahZulueta

Comment: There should be a *check* icon on the left of my answer.